# iOS: Adjust Height of UIWebView - Strange Behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, scrollview

I have a question. In `Xcode` I have a `ViewController` with embed View > `ScrollView` and inside of the Scrollview is a UIWebView.

The application reads some XML data und paste formatted text into the `UIWebView`. After the `UIWebView-Element` is another Element, so I have to adjust the height of the `UIWebView` dynamically.

After loading the view everything is fine, but when i tap on the screen the view re-size the `scrollview` to its storyboard height.

Why ?

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{
aWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;    // Property available in iOS 5.0 and later
CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;

frame.size.width = 280;       // Your desired width here.
frame.size.height = 1;        // Set the height to a small one.

aWebView.frame = frame;       // Set webView's Frame, forcing the Layout of its embedded     scrollView with current Frame's constraints (Width set above).

frame.size.height = aWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;  // Get the corresponding         height from the webView's embedded scrollView.

aWebView.frame = frame;       // Set the scrollView contentHeight back to the frame itself.

NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", aWebView.frame.size.width, aWebView.frame.size.height);

// Position URL Label
CGRect frame_label = fachmesseDetailWebsite.frame;
NSLog(@"x: %f", frame_label.origin.x);
NSLog(@"y: %f", frame_label.origin.y);
frame_label.origin.y=aWebView.frame.size.height+115;//pass the cordinate which you want
frame_label.origin.x= 20;//pass the cordinate which you want
fachmesseDetailWebsite.frame= frame_label;
NSLog(@"x: %f", frame_label.origin.x);
NSLog(@"y: %f", frame_label.origin.y);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

whenever you are changing the frame you have to reload the webview then only webview frame will change whatever you put there other wise it doesn't effect on webview.

```
[webview reload];
```

EDIT:
 this one working

```
UIWebView *web=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>a { color: #db5226; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; } body { padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size:45px;font-family: Helvetica;text-align:left; color:black; } </style></head<body>%@</body></html>",@"helow"];
    [web loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:web];
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is how I add the content to the webview:
`NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>a { color: #db5226; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; } body { padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size:13px;font-family: Helvetica;text-align:left; color:black; } </style></head<body>%@</body></html>",item.description];
[self.fachmesseDetailText loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];`

When I reload the webview everythink is blank...

Comment: see this tutorial http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/16673-UIWebview-load-url.html

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a webview placed in storyboard?

Comment: you can add webview in storyboard apps no problem.